# can a bathroom or kitchen exhaust airt through a vent placed in the outter edge of the soffit and pointing down and out

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, venting, soffit, exhaust

Can a bathroom or kitchen range vent out through a vent-unit placed on the outter-edge of a soffit if it is pointing down and away from the house?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I'm not sure enough, I have a couple of those on my house for bathrooms. I believe there are spacing rules from operable windows that you should check on.   Not sure about a range vent, but I think that's ok too.  Hopefully others here can give a more definitive answer.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson there are definitely spacing rules for plumbing vents, which releases sewer gases to atmosphere. I’m not so sure about vent fans that are only pushing most or slightly smelly air out of a room, but you might be right.